# ruby on rails: polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

In [Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), is `imageable` a model? And does `imageable` have a database table?

How does `imageable_id` point to two different `id` attributes for Employee and Product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in the page that you linked, imageable represents a polymorphic association to either an Employee or Product.  In order for the polymorphic association to work, rails will need to determine the 'type' of object (i.e.  either an Employee or a Product) by looking at the 'imageable_type' entry in the db and then the id of the respective object (imageable_id).

For example, an entry within the db of imageable_type => 'Employee' and and imageable_id => '4'.  ActiveRecord would figure out that the association is to id 4 in the employees table.

Comment: Ok, I understand where my misunderstanding came from. I though polymorphic association could be used for cases where Image model belongs to Employee and Product **at the same time**. Not one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

The imageable_type helps rails understand that which class the model belongs to. 
While generating model if you use `imageable:references` then rails will automatically generate imageable_id and imageable_type columns in your migration.

Answer (score 1):

Imageable is not a model.  It is a placeholder for some model (in this case either Employee or Product).

The way `imageable_id` can point to different kinds of ids is that Picture also has an `imageable_type` attribute.  For a given instance of Picture, it knows what kind of id `imageable_id` represents by looking at it's `imageable_type`.